# How to make case sensitive query with nodejs + pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, case-sensitive

How to make case sensitive query with nodejs + pg

I want to select column content == 'a@gmail.com',
 but it seems become select column == 'a@gmail.com'?

```
[error: column "a@gmail.com" does not exist]
```

code

```
var userEmail = 'a@gmail.com';

var query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE "Email" = "'+userEmail+'")';
dbClient.query(query, function(error, result) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with case. The problem is that you're putting the email address in double-quotes, and in (most varieties of) SQL double-quotes indicate a column name or table name. That's why the error message says `column "a@gmail.com" does not exist`.

Use single-quotes around values:

```
var userEmail = 'a@gmail.com';
var query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE "Email" = \'' + userEmail + '\')';
```

Ideally, though, you should just use parameter binding so you don't have to worry about quoting values at all. When you use string concatenation to build SQL queries you very often open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Do you know how to use parameter with `pg`  something like this `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE "Email" = $userEmail)';`   `dbClient.query(query, $userEmail, function(error, result) {`

Comment: Assuming you're using the node-postgres module, you should read the documentation on parameterized queries, here: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements

Answer (score 2):

For use binding parameters you must number it begining with `$1` (then `$2` and so), then put the parameters in an Array:

```
var query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE "Email" = $1)';
dbClient.query(query, [userEmail], function(error, result) {
```

Always pass the parameters in an array. Is most secure.

Remember do not pass a function to query if you have a very big table unless you want to read all the table before returns the control to de function. Else you can use the "on" event or use a promise way (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise-strict)

Comment: Thanks for reply, what is `pass a function to query`?

Comment: see the note in https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#parameters-1 "note: do not provide this function for large result sets unless you're okay with loading the entire result set into memory". In that cases you can use: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#simple-query-without-callback or https://github.com/codenautas/pg-promise-strict#example-with-fetch-row-by-row